# Boot Problems after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: boot, 19.04

Since upgrading to 19.04 (Unity) I get the attached screen when I reboot? What might the problem be...and what should I do?

[image: Boot Screen]

Comment: Is it a laptop? Is it dual booted? If so, can you log onto Windows-10? After upgrade to 19.04 did you ever log into Ubuntu, at least once? Did you upgrade from 18.04? Please give more description about your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, this is a normal GRUB screen. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes it is the normal GRUB screen....but this pops up automatically everytime  I reboot....This should not happen....well has not happened before in 10 years of using Ubuntu.

Comment: No, this is not a dual boot machine, nor a laptop. I boor into Unity (which is my preferred setup) I did try others....this may be where the problem is coming from?

Comment: ..I seem to have 2 Home directories...my regular one and a snap one!...not sure how I managed that. This might be the source of my problems....how should I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of it you could alter the file
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
look for the timeout fields 
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
and alter yours to 0
I had the opposite problem and had to alter the following two exception clauses from timeout=0 to timeout=10 otherwise I would not see that grub menu. 
shorter answer: just press the enter key to continue booting.
note too that any update-grub will put back in the default grub.cfg, so you will need to do it again.